# ggplot how to plot pie charts on USA map with plot_usmap package or geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, usmap, scatterpie

I want to plot my data over US map and also add pie charts on the map. I used geom_polygon and also  plot_usmap with geom_scatterpie but none of them worked. This my data https://iastate.box.com/s/rllzhkfmab475zr4ywur56cd31jhwl8g

```
f1<-ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(aes(x, y, group = region),
              data = total, cols = "fuel",pie_scale = 1.3, long_format=TRUE) +
               facet_grid(growth ~ emission)+
               geom_text(aes(x, y, label = region),size = 4,family = "serif",
               data = total, vjust = 1.2, nudge_y = -100000,check_overlap = TRUE)+
               scale_fill_manual(legend_title,values=mypal[names(mypal) %in% total[,2]])+
                theme(legend.title = element_text(family="sans",face = "bold", size = 12), legend.text = element_text(family="sans",size = 11),legend.position = "bottom")+
                theme(strip.text = element_text(family="sans",size = 14))+
                 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "gray"))
f1+ggplot(states_data, aes(x, y, fill = value, group = group)) +
 geom_polygon()+
scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "red", name = "Ele gen (EJ)", label = 
 scales::comma) +
 facet_grid(growth ~ emission) +
coord_equal() +
ggthemes::theme_map() +
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

and also this

```
 plot_usmap(data=states_data,values = "value", regions = "states", exclude = c("AK", "HI")) 
   +scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "red", name = "Ele gen (EJ)", label = 
    scales::comma)+
     geom_scatterpie(aes(x, y, group = region),
               data = total, cols = "fuel",pie_scale = 1.3, long_format=TRUE) +
              facet_grid(growth ~ emission)+
               geom_text(aes(x, y, label = region),size = 4,family = "serif",
               data = total, vjust = 1.2, nudge_y = -100000,check_overlap = TRUE)+
                scale_fill_manual(legend_title,values=mypal[names(mypal) %in% total[,2]])+
                   theme(legend.title = element_text(family="sans",face = "bold", size = 12), 
               legend.text = element_text(family="sans",size = 11),legend.position = "bottom")+
           theme(strip.text = element_text(family="sans",size = 14))+
           theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "gray"))
```

I want to plot this two together:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you help me with this? @stefan

Comment: Hi, could you help me with this one too? thanks @tjebo